# gdb Debugger Remot localhost

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

Could someone help me with this?
I need to do the debugger step by step with the GDB but it is aborted.

```
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
warning: Exception condition detected on fd 536
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried normal c code with it and it worked quite well but when I use it with my big project it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

The errors `warning: Exception condition detected on fd 536` and `Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: No such file or directory.` almost always mean that the remote target has died unexpectedly.

You didn't mention if you are using standard gdbserver, or some other remote target, but if you start your remote target in a separate terminal, and then connect GDB and step through, you should notice that your remote target exits (crashes maybe?), and this will correspond to the time when GDB throws the above error.

You should file a bug against whoever provides your remote target.  If this is stock gdbserver, then that would be the GDB project itself, but if it is some other remote target, then you should approach them.